# JS - List to an array separated by coma

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, list

I have a function which the output shows as a list:

```
email1
email2
email3
…
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have an array output that looks like:

```
email1, email2, email3, …
```

Any idea how could I convert the list ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".select_email").click(function(){
           var val = [];

           $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                val[i] = $(this).val();
                var arr = jQuery.makeArray( val[i] );
                arr.push(val[i]);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;
                console.log(arr);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quick solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select_email").click(function(){
  var val = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){ return this.value; }).toArray().join(', ');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'v an array. I just convert this staff.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select_email").click(function(){
       var val = [];

       $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            val[i] = $(this).val();
            var arr = jQuery.makeArray( val[i] );
            arr.push(val[i]);

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val[i];
            console.log(val[i]);
            //we just convert array to string by separator comma
            console.log(arr.join(", "));

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: only last email will show in DOM, you are overwriting each iteration

Comment: Hi, I'v create jsfiddle demo, it's working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kmb645/hqe4wuxc/18/

Comment: but fiddle uses different code than what is shown in answer

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things with an extra array. You only need one array and use `join()`

```
$(".select_email").click(function () {
    var val = [];

    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
        val.push($(this).val());// push values to array    
    });
    $('#demo').html(val.join()); // join array to print

});
```

By default `join()` uses a comma as delimitter, if you want extra space or different delimitter pass as argument like `join(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is, you are printing the values. You already have the list

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

on which you are performing the $.each operation. You can get the item by specifying the second argument.

```
$(selector).each(function(index, elem){
     //do stuff
})
```

for more information, you can review the API documentation
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace var "txt" with your data.

Example:

```
<textarea id="txtarea">
line1
line2
linea3</textarea>

    function transform(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('txtarea').value;
        txt = txt.replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br/>');
        var temp = txt.split("<br/>");

        var rsp = '';

        for (index = 0; index < temp.length; ++index) {
            rsp += temp[index]  + " ";
        }

        console.log(rsp);
    }
```

Output:

line1 line2 line3